# pass array values from AJAx to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am facing some issues. I am trying to insert array in `MYSQL` using `AJAX` and `PHP` but its not working following is my code:

HTML:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="invoice" id="invoice"   placeholder="piece">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pieces[]" id="pieces" placeholder="Qty">
```

I want to pass fields from ajax to php. I am using following code in ajax.

```
var inv = $("#invoice").val();
var pieces = $("#pieces").val();

$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "query.php",
    data: "piece="+pieces+"&inv="+inv,
    success: function(data){

        $("#result").html(data);
    }

});
```

following is the PHP code:

```
<?php
$piece = $_POST[piece];
foreach ($piece as $key => $value) {
    $query = mysql_query(insert into items values('$value', '$_POST[inv]');
}

?>
```

Comment: The quotes are messed up in your PHP code, as you can see from the syntax highlighting. You'll also need to append the `$_POST['inv']` value to the string, not just include it in the string literal

Comment: Your ajax data format is not for POST. It's in GET format.

Comment: why do you ignore your number one debugging tool(Console and Network Tab)? Alot of errors of info are there.

Comment: Use ```data: {piece:piece, inv:inv}``` inplace of ```data: "piece="+pieces+"&inv="+inv,``` in your Jquery code.

Comment: Is that all the PHP code? have you opened the SQL connection first? the network tab will show you what the ajax is querying and the result returned

Comment: `data: {"piece":pieces,"inv":inv},`  and then $_POST['piece'] and $_POST[inv'']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code
jQuery

```
var inv = $("#invoice").val();
var pieces = $("#pieces").val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "query.php",
    data: {'in':inv,'pi':pieces},
    success: function(data){
       $("#result").html(data);
    }
});
```

php

```
<?php
$pieces = $_POST[piece];
foreach($pieces as $piece){
{
$query = mysql_query(insert into items values ('$piece','$_POST[inv]');
}
?>
```

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in G:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\admin\query.php on line 88

Comment: var pieces=[];$("input[type=text][name^=pieces[]]").filter(function() {
 pieces.push($(this).val());
}).get(); $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "query.php",
    data: {'in':inv,'pi':pieces},
    success: function(data){
       $("#result").html(data);
    }
});  pls try this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

JQuery:

```
var inv = $("#invoice").val();
var pieces = $("#pieces").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "query.php",
    data: {'in':inv,'pi':pieces},
    success: function(data){
       $("#result").html(data);
    }
});
```

Php code :

```
<?php
    $inv = $_POST['in'];
    $piece = $_POST['pi'];

    $query = mysql_query(insert into items values '$piece','$_POST[inv]');
?>
```

This is the simple example, please use mysql encapsulation to get value for preventing sql injection.

Comment: its only inserting the single item not array.  i have 5 fields of pieces[] but it only inserted the first one